# Shiny error : data not being read when connected with a database

Tags: r, shiny

**An overview of the project**: To connect with a postgres DB that contains id,scores and date, so that a shiny dashboard user can enter the id and next I want to compute an upper and lower ranges for the mean(scores) for that id, so that finally I can display all that in a graph.

**Issue**: Looks like no data is being read from the DB, **error: scores not found**

Below is the script:

```
library(ALL relevant libraries)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

con<-dbConnect(drv,dbname = "", host = "", port = "", user = "", password= "")
# correct credentials placed above

dates <- seq(as.Date(as.character(Sys.Date() - 10)), as.Date(as.character(Sys.Date() - 5)), by = 1)
# dates vector should have 5 days 

r <<- length(dates)


ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Score"),

sidebarPanel(numericInput(inputId = "id",label = "user", value = 0000 ,
                        min = 100, max = 1000000)),

mainPanel(plotOutput("Coolplot"))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  browser()

  generate <- function(r) {

 listofdfs <- list() # Create a list in which you intend to save your df's. 

 for (i in 1:length(dates)) {

  data <- dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("select score, CAST (date AS date), id from My_Table 
                                         where id = ",input$id," and
                                date<=date('%s') and date>=date('%s')- INTERVAL '7 day'",dates[i],dates[i])) 

    # changed the date<='%s' to date<=date('%s') now at least can read the data. 


   data$score_mean <- mean(data[,1])

   data$upper_threshold <- data$score_mean * 1.2

   data$lower_threshold <- data$score_mean * 0.8

  listofdfs[[i]] <- data # save your dataframes into the list
  }

  return(listofdfs) #Return the list of dataframes.
}


 df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", generate(r)))
 df<-reactive({df[!duplicated(df$date)]}) #since data needed some subsetting




output$Coolplot <- renderPlot({

    browser()
    ggplot(df(), aes(date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = score, colour = "score"))+
    geom_line(aes(y = upper_threshold, colour = "upper_threshold")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = lower_threshold, colour = "lower_threshold"))
})
}


 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you all for your help.

Cheers!

Comment: if you want to change the user_id the generate should be a reactive.

Comment: You can remove the r parameter that you don't use anyway, and also note that you should use `inputId = "user_id"

Comment: @HubertL....Hi my friend...Thank you again for replying...so are you saying that I should have reactive wrapped up around generate at line 34ish?

Comment: I removed "input$id" and passed a static id, hoping that it will grab the data but that still did not work. So my main error at the moment is: it looks like my script is not fetching any data, while my table is does contain data. Not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Always develop your code outside of shiny where debugging is easier

Comment: you could pass the user_id to the generate function

Comment: Note the sprintf syntax is `sprintf(fmt, ...)` so `%s` outside of fmt string won't produce expected effects. Currently your request is `select score, CAST (date AS date), id from My_Table where id = ` which is invalid

Comment: Thanks Hubert...you are right, I should debug it outside shiny, I am doing it now and have realized that problem may be with sprintf(), also this time when I passed static id, I still did not get any data...so now my guess is problem is in date variable and date range in relation to postgres...

Comment: After passing date as explicit date type, I can get the data and script working as non shiny. Now I have to make it shiny by passing generate function inside reactive. Please help Hubert ...Thanks

Comment: Post your new code, I'll try to have a look at it later today.

Comment: Thanks Hubert...I have updated the script in the question. P.S I only had to add date()in sprintf command and now....in order for me to accept input from user, dbGetQuery will need to be wrapped inside reactive...but if that is wrapped inside reactive then I am not sure how my other operations will be performed (mean,upper and lower range), and hopefully if I can accept input form user as reactive and perform operations of the DF received, then my programme should run :)

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think you should set an initial value under the `min`

`sidebarPanel(numericInput(inputId = "id",label = "user", value = 0000 , min = 100, max = 1000000)),`

=>

`sidebarPanel(numericInput(inputId = "id",label = "user", value = 100 , min = 100, max = 1000000)),`

2. Keep generate as a regular function returning something based on provided parameters

`generate <- function(r) {`

=>

`generate <- function(user_id) {`

3. don't mix up `sprintf` with `paste` and [prevent SQL injection](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sql-injections.html)

`sprintf("select score, CAST (date AS date), id from My_Table where id = ",input$id," and date<=date('%s') and date>=date('%s')- INTERVAL '7 day'",dates[i],dates[i]))`

=>

`sprintf("select score, CAST (date AS date), id from My_Table where id = %d and date<=date('%s') and date>=(date('%s')- INTERVAL '7 day')", as.numeric(user_id), as.date(dates[i]), as.date(dates[i])))`

4. Add all your data manipuation within the reactive that references `input` parameters

`df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", generate(r)))
df<-reactive({df[!duplicated(df$date)]})`

=>

`df<-reactive({
     data <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", generate(input$id)))
     data[!duplicated(data$date)]
})`

Comment: Thank you very much @Hubert...it finally worked..you saved my weekend :)

Comment: I'm glad it did. Have a sunny week-end!